# How can I constrain to properties to be of the same type?

Tags: typescript, generics, types

I want to create objects whose properties are parametrized with the same generic type `T`.

It seems that this kind of logic is partially supported by generic functions, which can infer `T` at call time, but this isn't enough.

```js
type Pair<T> = {
  a: T
  b: T
}

type PairArray = Array<Pair> // Generic type 'Pair' requires 1 type argument(s).

type PairFactory = <T>() => Pair<T>

type PairArrayFactory = Array<PairFactory>

const pairArrayFactory: PairArrayFactory = [() => {return {a: '', b: ''}}] // T' could be instantiated with an arbitrary type which could be unrelated to 'string'.
```

How can I tell the compiler that each time I create an `Pair` that the properties should be of the same type, but that I don't care what that type is?

I really want to be able to fill this array with whatever I was so long as `a` and `b` are of the same type:

```js
const pairArray: PairArray = [
  { a: 1, b: 2 },
  { a: 'foo', b: 'bar' },
  ...
]
```

Comment: There is no specific type that works this way in TypeScript, but you can write a generic type and a helper function that enforces this, as shown [in this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/wXOvQW).  Does that meet your needs? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: @jcalz yes that seems to work. Please feel free to make an answer and I’ll accept it. Can you include a bit more detail about how you went about solving it?

Answer (score 0):

The `any` type will not work for this case, so we need to specify the types we would like to support on the type and passed in as the generic. Here is a base to get you started.

```js
type Pair<T> = T extends string
  ? { a: string; b: string }
  : T extends number
  ? { a: number; b: number }
  : T extends boolean
  ? { a: boolean; b: boolean }
  : never;

const pairArray: Pair<string | number | boolean>[] = [
  { a: "string one", b: "string 2" }, // pass
  { a: 1, b: 2 }, // pass
  { a: true, b: false }, // pass
  { a: 1, b: "string" }, // fail
  { a: false, b: "string" }, // fail
  { a: true, b: 5 } // fail
];
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to say that a `PairArray` is an array where each element is a `Pair<T>` for *some* [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) `T` you don't care about.  But TypeScript doesn't have the ability to directly represent the idea of "some generic".  That would require [*existentially quantified generics*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_system#Existential_types)  as requested in [microsoft/TypeScript#14466](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/14466#).  But TypeScript doesn't have such generics (to be fair to TypeScript, few languages do) so we'll need a different approach.  That means you can't directly represent `PairArray` as a specific type.

---

Instead you can try represent it as a generic type like `type PairArray<T extends any[]>` where `T` represents the [tuple](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#tuple-types) of type parameters for `Pair`.  So a value of type `[Pair<X>, Pair<Y>, Pair<Z>]` would be `PairArray<[X, Y, Z]>`.   By default this would require you to write out `[X, Y, Z]`, but you can make a generic helper function called `pairArray()` which *infers* this type for you.

So instead of writing

```
const pa: PairArray = [{ a: 1, b: 2 }, { a: 'foo', b: 'bar' }, ...];
```

you *could* write

```
const pa: PairArray<[number, string, ...]> = 
 [{ a: 1, b: 2 }, { a: 'foo', b: 'bar' }, ...];
```

but you'd *actually* write

```
const pa = pairArray([{ a: 1, b: 2 }, { a: 'foo', b: 'bar' }, ...]);
```

which is fairly similar to the desired version in terms of amount of code.

---

So how can you write `PairArray<T>`? You could first try the
[mapped tuple type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-1.html#mapped-types-on-tuples-and-arrays)

```
type PairArray<T extends any[]> = { [I in keyof T]: Pair<T[I]> }
```

and the helper function `pairArray()` would be:

```
const pairArray = <T extends any[]>(arr: [...PairArray<T>]) => arr;
```

and note that we wrapped the type of `arr` in a [variadic tuple type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-0.html#variadic-tuple-types) (that's the `[...` and `]`) just so that calling `pairArray()` will tend to infer tuples and not unordered arrays.

Let's try it out:

```
const p = pairArray([
    { a: 1, b: 2 },
    { a: 'foo', b: 'bar' },
    { a: 1, b: "bar" },
    { a: true, b: false }
]); // no error
// const p: [Pair<number>, Pair<string>, Pair<string | number>, Pair<boolean>]
```

Hmm... in some sense it works perfectly, but probably not how you'd want it to.  Indeed, that third element really is of the type `Pair<string | number>`, since the values `1` and `"bar"` are both of the [union type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) `string | number`.  But you probably consider that a mistake.  You don't want the compiler to infer the generic type parameter from *both* the `a` and the `b` properties.  Instead you probably want it to infer from, say, `a`, and then just *check* it against `b`.  So in `type Pair<T> = {a: T, b: T}`, you'd like the `T` on `b` to be a *non-inferential type parameter usage*, as requested in [microsoft/TypeScript#14829](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/14829).

---

As mentioned in that issue there's no *direct* support for that, but there are workarounds which, depending on use case, have that effect.  One way to do it is to introduce an extra type parameter that is [constrained](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints) to the first, and use that type parameter in the "non-inferential" position:

```
type Pair<T, U extends T = T> = {
    a: T
    b: U
}

type PairArray<T extends any[], U extends T = T> =
    { [I in keyof T]: Pair<T[I], U[I]> }

const pairArray = <T extends any[], U extends T = T>(
    arr: [...PairArray<T, U>]) => arr;

const p = pairArray([
    { a: 1, b: 2 },
    { a: 'foo', b: 'bar' },
    { a: 1, b: "bar" }, // error! Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'number'.
    { a: true, b: false }
]);
// const p: [Pair<number, number>, Pair<string, string>, 
//           Pair<number, number>, Pair<boolean, boolean>]
```

Great, that works how you want!  `T` is inferred only from the `a` properties and `U` is inferred from the `b` properties, and as long as `U` extends `T` everything is fine.  If not, then the `U` inference fails and there's a warning on the `b` property.

---

But maybe we don't want to actually change the definition of `Pair` since `Pair<number, number>` is redundant... and we don't even really need to define `PairArray` if all we're using it for is for inference in the `pairArray()` function.  Which brings us, finally, to this version:

```
const pairArray = <T extends any[], U extends T>(arr: [...{
    [I in keyof T]: { a: T[I], b: U[I] } }
]): { [I in keyof T]: Pair<T[I]> } => arr;
   
const p = pairArray([
    { a: 1, b: 2 },
    { a: 'foo', b: 'bar' },
    { a: 1, b: "bar" }, // error! 
    { a: true, b: false }
]);
// const p: [Pair<number>, Pair<string>, Pair<number>, Pair<boolean>]
```

Which still works and produces a more ergonomic output.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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-yCQtCp6kgK5LCJS1K0gQ9IcNwvACFAACaEAloQDS+s0oJliUIbmtG+qpIaxoEWaFpZDkliprKSrWLY9hOC47hoJ4Tb0H4zyem6AQBE+5QUBYdF2oxjosc6gGuv4DBVKQ+bMIWWGtLg7RBhWja9u2dYNj2V4tqszydme3Zyhp4z9uc0zDkCcJIOOU6XgMdyPM896fLxPzlH8JCvopYKWBCX7wgB2J3GioGAYF4WoOBkEsDSdJAA)